# how to get a list of files with .html extension using PHP scandir?

Tags: php

I am using the following code to get a list of files and folders in a directory.
this works fine. but what I need to do is to only get a list of HTML files in that directory and ignoring the rest of the files and folders.

this is my code:

```
$path = "../";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/".$value."' target='_black' >".$value."</a><br/>";
}
```

I've tried this and still get all the files and folders:

```
$indir = scandir('../');
$fileextensions = array(".", "html");
$indir = array_diff($indir, array('.', '..'));
$replaceextensions = str_replace($fileextensions, "", $indir);

foreach ($indir as &$value) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/".$value."' target='_black' >".$value."</a><br/>";
}
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

with the code bellow I can get the list of html files example( `page1.html, page2.html` etc). however, some of my html files have names like `page1.tpl.html`, `page2.tpl.html` etc and I cannot get those files in the list even though their extension is ending with `.html`.

could someone please advise on this?

this is my code now:

```
$path = "../";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = glob("*.{html}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/".$value."' target='_black' >".$value."</a><br/>";
}
```

Comment: [`glob()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.glob.php) could come in handy.

Comment: preg_match('/\.html/',$indir,$result) ?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, so is it not possible to do it using `scandir` ?

Comment: pathinfo() function get help you too.

Comment: That I can't say for sure. I've always used `glob()`. You probably could slip it into your first code.

Comment: `scandir()` does not have the functionality you are looking for. However, You can search the resulting array afterward and discard files not matching your criteria.

Comment: Sidenote: `target='_black'` should be `target='_blank'` and try the answer below, and fixing the same typo; it works.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, sorry that was a typo. Also, i Answered my own question lol. although with your help so thank you very much. I have another question though which I'm not sure if i need to ask it here or i need to open a new question!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, you might have to post another question. Go ahead; shoot. I'll see if I can help real quick like ;-) If I can't, you'll have to post another question.

Comment: You know that you can post your solution as an answer too.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, i have posted my solution as the answer bellow. the answer is mine. :). I've also edited my question with my new question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- cheers for +1 mate. :) any solution for the new question?

Comment: Try `$files = glob("*.{tpl,html}", GLOB_BRACE);` which worked for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, No, Unfortunately that still gets the page1.html, page2.html etc.

Comment: Actually, the additional `tpl` isn't needed, I retested. Something else is causing this.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, i have nothing else(no other codes) in my php page to cause this though!

Comment: Are you sure you've chosen the right path? I honestly don't know what else could be causing this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah.. 100% sure. all the page(s).html files are in the same directory as the page(s).tpl.html files but it only lists the page(s).html and ignores the page(s).tpl.html files.

Comment: You don't have any rewrites, something in `.htaccess`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i do but nothing to do with .html or .tpl.html files! i only have some rewrites for .php files.

Comment: If you're running this from your own machine, try and restart PHP/Apache. I can't see how it could not accept `.tpl.html` files; *baffled*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm running it on a live server. it is a shared server though. not sure why it doesn't accept .tpl.html either! very strange.

Comment: I've seen certain servers act up differently when it comes to some settings. If you're able to test it on another server not hosted by the same people, that might help. My server's running 5.4.2 on Linux.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, i think you are right. I will run a test on another server to see if it works there. I even tried `$info = new SplFileInfo('mypage.tpl.html');
var_dump($info->getExtension());` and it returns the "html" so there must be the server issue. Thanks for your time and help mate.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$path = "../";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = glob("*.{html}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/".$value."' target='_black' >".$value."</a><br/>";
}
```